# Has FB.Canvas.setAutoResize() stopped working for anyone else?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I maintain a few different Facebook applications, and across them I use

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
```

to resize the height of the application.

In the last few hours this has stopped working on all of my applications, without any of my code being changed.

I found a user that seems to have the same problem [here](http://boardreader.com/thread/FB_Canvas_setSize_Not_working_on_Chrome_6cxfqX1mxy.html).

My main question is, has anyone else had this happen to their applications today?

Does anyone know if this is a bug or has support for setAutoResize() suddenly been dropped?

Comment: For future reference, this was a Facebook issue and has been fixed.

Comment: @Tapos are you still having the problem? It's been intermittent at best for me and the past few days it hasn't been working at all.

Comment: i haven't face this. but still the bug status is "assigned" so yet they haven't solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, live platform status says FB team is working on this. For more please check [here](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status/) and [here](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17959)

Answer (score 0):

Other users seem to be having this issue as well http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10889